# Android background image - imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have one activity, and I set imageview element to match parent with one of my background image with dimensions: 1440x2560 . I need to make this image on fullscrean. But whenever I put that image using scaleType="fitXY" I get this:
[image]

**XML layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.backgroundApp.SecondActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.backgroundApp;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#004d40")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `scaletype = centerCrop`?

Comment: Did you already have the answer?

Comment: @AjilO. It's a little bigger but again not on fullscreen...

Comment: @SteveYo Are you sure you are doing everything right? both the answers in this thread work for me. Try using a different image

Answer (score 3):

Use **adjustViewBounds=true** property in **ImageView** tag like

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: I get this error: Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'adjustViewBounds' in package 'com.backgroundApp'

Comment: please check i changed my answer

Comment: tried with android also, but still get the same image which is not on fullscrean. :/

Answer (score 1):

use **[setAdjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)**

`setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds)`

**Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.**

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

**or try to set programatically**

```
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
 imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: I get this error: Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'adjustViewBounds' in package 'com.backgroundApp'

Comment: declare name space     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: tried with android also, but still get the same image which is not on fullscrean. :/

Comment: try to set programaticaaly@SteveYo

Answer (score 0):

change

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/xxxxx"
```